# Laravel : Missing required parameters for [Route: objets.update]

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I have a table objects, I want to make a form with only one field where the user puts in the object id and it allows them to update that object.

the error I get is this:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: objets.update] [URI: objets/{objet}]. (View: D:\Documents\fac18-19\semestre4\Projet\findlost\resources\views\objets\update.blade.php)
```

my form is as follows : (in views/objets/update.blade.php)

```php
@extends('template_base')

@section('page')
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div id="to-send" class="row">
    <!--{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/objID/'))}}-->
    {{ Form::open(array('action' => "ObjetsController@update")) }}
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ Form::label('id','ID de l\'objet :', ['class'=>'control-label']) }}
      {{ Form::text('id',null ,array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ Form::submit('Envoyer', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'))}}
    </div>
    {{ Form::close()}}
  </div>
</div>
<br>
@endsection
```

My update method is empty for now, I wanted to be able to pass an ID as a parameter as well but I have an error with that as well :

```php
  public function update(Request $request) //I wanted an $id here
  {
    //return view("/profile");
  }
```

So I expect to be able to update a specific object with the help of this form, what am I doing wrong ?

(I have the following routs :

```php
Route::resource('objets', 'ObjetsController');
//Route::post('/objID/{id}', 'ObjetsController@update')->name('obj_id');
```

the second didn't help)

Comment: The only issue standing out to me is that you are spelling `object` incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Route::resource('objets', 'ObjetsControlle`r');

the update route would be

`objets/{objet}`, so 
`{{ Form::open(array('action' => "ObjetsController@update")) }}` should be

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => "ObjetsController@update", $objet))) }}
```

You may prefer `{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'objets.update', ['objet' => $objet]))) }}` too

and

```
public function update(Request $request){}
```

should be `public function update(Request $request, Objets $objet){}`